# Managing configuration in Perl

Tags: perl, configuration

Currently I'm storing configuration as default values in respective objects. But this is very hard to maintain, because the configuration is split into thousand pieces.

Is there some commonly used approach to store and retrieve per-class configuration in Perl?

Comment: Are you asking for ways to store configuration outside your code in general or do you have something more specific in mind? Depending on what kind of classes you build you might want configuration files, a database table, an additional module which holds all the defaults and is used by the others, or something completely different.

Comment: Well, it could be an ini file, it could be something perl specific, it is for mostly static configuration, so database is overkill and unpractical. Basically I'm asking what is generally used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't really a One True Configuration Format in Perl. YAML, INI files, a simple name=value list, or a custom XML schema are all in common use. Better to just pick one and run with it than stewing about it.